# Check if cell as text contains anything other than 0 to 9

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of ill formatted cells, and I'm extracting the ones that have something that is not a number, but the value iN the cells is text(String), so IsNumeric won't work

For example :

4884756921

488475692?

487575e75484

I want to find the ones that have text without changing it

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
'' i is where i'm storing what is found

For j = 1 To Rows.Count

    If Len(Cells(j, 4)) = 20 Then

            Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(j, 4)
            Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(j, 4).Row + 1
            Cells(j, 4).Value = ""
            i = i + 1

    End If

Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: So you have cells with "0", "123", "three", and "elephant", for example? So you'd just want to pull out "Elephant"?

Comment: Are you looking for an excel formula or VBA solution? Also, what does "but the value is the cells is text," mean? Is that supposed to be "but the format of the cell is text"? Could you share some sample data?

Comment: VBA preferably, I edited the question

Comment: try this `If Not IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Evaluate("--" & selection.address(0,0))) Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner that returned nothing, what is the parameters for selection.adress?

Comment: You would change selection to the range object in your loop.  Without your code it is hard to customize.

Comment: @ScottCraner I used j,4 as in the example above and didn't work

Comment: did you get an error? did it not find any numbers? `didn't work` is not very descriptive.

Comment: returned nothing, worked but nothing happened

Comment: Sorry, there must be unprintable characters in the cells that are keeping it from resolving to numbers.  you may find that there are line breaks or spaces.

Comment: One last idea to try, `If Not isnumeric(activesheet.evaluate("--TRIM(CLEAN(" & Cells(j,4).address(0,0) & "))")) then`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112082/discussion-between-mojimi-and-scott-craner).

Comment: Why not just get the `Len()` of your cell, then step through each character with `Mid()`, and `isNumber()` (or whatever that is in VB)?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the VAL function could be used to test if the string contains non-numeric values, but it appears that VAL does not recognise the “?” symbol as non-numeric. (the worksheet function VALUE does work, but VALUE is not available as application.WorksheetFunction.

However application.WorksheetFunction.IsNonText exist, which does test if the cell contains a value (and correctly asserts the “?” as non-numeric). Prerequisite: the cell format does need to be general or number (not text).

=> I expect this would work:

```
If not application.WorksheetFunction.IsNonText(Cells(j, 4))
```

The simpler solution is to identify the ill-formatted cells with the VALUE function directly in the worksheet. (`=IFERROR(VALUE(A4),"contains character"`)